# How to wait for a asynchronous method execution and then execute synchronous statements in angular7

Tags: typescript, asynchronous, angular7, synchronous

I googled a lot on how to wait for asynchronous and then execute synchronous in angular7, but no luck so far. 
in my component I have two methods loadList() simpleMethod_1().

On a click event simpleMethod_1() is triggered which then calls loadList()

I tried to use angular async-await, but didn't work or may be I didn't configure it in a right way!!
I also tried setting timer which works the way I want to ( line number 7-10 executes), but when the internet is very slow then it fails.

```
loadList() {
    this.loadingGif = true;
    this.service.resetAllStoredData(); 
    // get the list data from server
    this.service.getAllList().subscribe(list => {
      this.list = list;
      // save the list so as to retrieve again
      this.service.setList(list); //sync
      this.loadingGif = false; 
    });
  }


simpleMethod_1(){

  1. const storedId = this.localStroageService.getStoredId();
  2. this.loadList();   
  3. console.log("aap loading 1", this.loadingGif)

    4. if (
      storedId !== null &&
      storedId !== undefined 
    ) {
      5. console.log("aap loading 2", this.loadingGif)

      6. if (!this.loadingGif) {
        // check before navigating
        7. const data = this.list.find(item => item.id === storedId );

         8. if (!data.complete) {
          // remember to store routing info
          // fetch user data 
         9.  this.getUserDetails();//synchronous

         10.  this.router.navigate("somepath")
        }
      }//end of loadingGif if

    }
}//end of method
```

(NOTE: I purposely gave numbers so I can point out what I'm talking)

ISSUE: 
What happens is whenever simpleMethod_1() is called,  after line #1, asynchronous method loadList() gets called and the lines 3-5 gets executed before even loadList() finishes execution! And because loadingGif is still true, line number 7-10 never executes.

What I want to achieve is, simpleMethod_1() will be triggered,
- line 1 executes,
- should call loadlist() and wait till it finishes and then come out from there
-and then execute line 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10 ...at end it should navigate to different page

Could anyone suggest how can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

Here's a solution

```
async simpleMethod1() 

{


await this.loadList()

}

async loadList() {

   var result = await this.service.getAllList();

}


async getAllList(): Promise<any>
{

    this.httpService.get().toPromise()

}
```

Comment: thanks, but I believe I did try in all possible ways using async-await.

Comment: I have done it the same way as given, I was able to achieve the same behaivour which u want to achieve, try it

Answer (score 0):

I resolved the issue using pipe and tap, posting answer just in case anyone finds this helpful.

```
loadList(): Observable<something[]> {
    this.lodingGif = true;

    // get the list data from server
    return this.service.getAllList().pipe(
      tap(list => {
                   // statement..
                  //statement..
          });
}

simpleMethod_1(){
      this.loadList()
      .toPromise()
      .then(list => {
  1. statement...   
  3. console.log("aap loading 1", this.loadingGif)

    4. if (
      storedId !== null &&
      storedId !== undefined 
    ) {
      5. console.log("aap loading 2", this.loadingGif)

      6. if (!this.loadingGif) {
        // check before navigating
        7. const data = this.list.find(item => item.id === storedId );

         8. if (!data.complete) {
          // fetch user data 
         9.  this.getUserDetails();//synchronous

         10.  this.router.navigate("somepath")
        }
      }//end of loadingGif if

    }
 });

}//end of method
```